# Laravel 8 : Why session does not submitted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to add a session of `warning` like this at my Controller method:

`return view('panel.step3' , compact('factor' , 'showStep') )->with('warning' , 'test !');`

And then on view `panel.step3`, I have added this: `@dd(session('warning'))`

But it says: *NULL*

So what is going wrong here ? How can I properly add my session ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `->with()` on a `view()` doesn't add anything to the session. You'd access that via `$warning`. `redirect()->with('warning')` is when you'd use `session('warning')`.

Comment: Sorry, meant to add this to the comment above, edit time expired, if you want a session value when returning a view, you can simply do `session()->flash('warning', 'Test!')` right before `return view(...);`

Comment: @TimLewis Would you add it as an answer plz

Comment: In my personal experience, don't use `dd` while dealing with session. The session behaves odd way (sometimes) if you exit out of the flow with a `dd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with()` method performs differently based on where you chain it. For a `view()`:

```
return view('view.name')->with('variable', 'value');
```

The `'variable'` will be available as a variable, `$variable`, and not via the session `session()->get('variable')`.

When you use `with()` on a `redirect()`:

```
return redirect()->route('route.name')->with('variable', 'value');
```

Then the `'variable'` is available via `session()`, and not as `$variable`.

This is due to the request life-cycle; for `view()`, it's a single chain of calls, so setting a variable is acceptable. For `redirect()`, it needs to perform a brand new request, and variable persistence across calls is done via `session` logic.

If you wish to use `session()` with `view()`, simply do a `flash()`:

```
session()->flash('variable', 'value');
return view('view.name');
```

In this case, `session()->get('variable')` is valid, while `$variable` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Because you just render the view with data, not redirect to another action, so you didn't put anything to session.